# App getting slow after room with coroutine implementation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have migrated all database tables greenDao to Room with suspend function
App speed and performance getting slow when calling functions by CoroutineScope.

withContext(Dispatchers.IO) running very slow inside coroutineScope(Dispatcher.Main) while runBlocking work fast without coroutine

```
// This function running fast

    fun getValFromDb() {
      
            var objectOne: MyVal1 = runBlocking{ fetchFromTabelOne() }
            var objectTwo: MyVal2 = runBlocking{ fetchFromTableTwoById(objectOne.getId) }
            UpdateUi(objectTwo) 
        
    }



// This function running slow 
fun getValFromDb() {
   
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{ 
      
        var objectOne: MyVal = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ fetchFromDb() }
        
        var objectTwo: MyVal2 = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ fetchFromTableTwoById(objectOne.getId) }
        
        UpdateUi(objectTwo) 
    }
}
```

Note :We didn't found any solution or recommendation to implement runBlocking for production but CoroutineScope keeps slowing the app as compare to runBlocking

Comment: Where is `CoroutineScope` defined? This is usually the name of the interface, did you declare a variable with this name?

Comment: Also, why do you use `withContext(IO)` here? I don't know Room, but I believe the implementation of the `suspend` functions in the DAO should already dispatch on a proper dispatcher, so this is unnecessarily switching contexts.

Comment: I have used CoroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { }, I have many dependent   queries in one scope

Comment: What I mean is that there is no `launch` function defined on `CoroutineScope`'s companion object, so you need to have an actual instance of `CoroutineScope`, this code should not compile as-is, unless you defined a variable somewhere that has exactly the same name as the interface.

Comment: Joffery, I had remove withContext(IO) but app getting more slow on that point then I add withContext(IO) it is working better than before but when I removed all coroutineScope and just using runBlocking app performance and speed increasing automatically

Comment: i'm not getting point, could you give me an example if possible

Comment: Wrapping a suspend function call in `withContext` should only serve to possibly slow it down a tiny amount because of unnecessary context switching. Can you check that your code exactly matches what you're compiling? The `CoroutineScope` interface does not have a companion object with a `launch` function. Also, please show the contents of your two `fetch` functions.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I feel like we've written the same thing :D

Comment: Yes, but they overlooked or ignored your comment.

Comment: sorry there was a typo issue i have updated the question

Comment: i am using  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{  }

Comment: Thanks. That was the reason for our comments. I'm surprised you need to create your own scope like this. You should already have a coroutine scope like `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` (if you're on android). If not, you should tie this custom scope to the lifecycle of some component in your app (e.g. close it when your component dies), rather than just create it here and forget about it.

Comment: actually, the whole project made on MVP pattern. I have Model, view, Presenter, and table helper classes,  I am not able to use viewModelScope or lifecycleScope

Comment: and the issue occurs in the cursorAdapter there multiple queries running on scroll and updating the UI on run time. runBlocking working fine but when I am using coroutine it's getting too slow

Comment: @DanishKhan if `getValFromDb()` doesn't have access to these coroutine scopes because it lives elsewhere, it should rather receive a scope as argument or receiver (the convention is to use a `CoroutineScope` receiver). But then I'm surprised that it has a call to `UpdateUI` here, this would imply it's close to the view, where you should have a scope available.

Comment: Also, again, Room uses its own internal dispatcher to execute queries, so `withContext` will only slow things down.

Comment: I didn't get why runBlocking work fast even it close after completion and run on the Main thread

Comment: Could you check this, i have remove withContext() just added CoroutineScope(Dispatcher.Main).launch{}

https://www.codepile.net/pile/X0mVbpvR

Comment: i have added at line no 48

Comment: I had a quick look at your linked code, and I'm sorry but I can't see the big picture in this 200-line-long function. Apart from that, you shouldn't use `CoroutineScope` this way, you are creating new scopes all the time, but the point of scopes is to have a lifecycle, otherwise it's even worse than using `GlobalScope` (please have a look at its doc to see the problems with it). If you don't want to receive a coroutine scope from a component with lifecycle, you should create a single scope that you close when appropriate. Do not replace all `runBlocking` calls with a new scope creation.

Comment: "you should create a single scope that you close when appropriate." Thank you! I got your point, let me check how to implement it. In last could you clarify what does it mean "Do not replace all runBlocking calls with a new scope creation"

Comment: @DanishKhan I added a proper answer to avoid long discussions in comments. I'll update the answer if necessary with more details. This last sentence was referring to the fact that you use `CoroutineScope()` in many places, which is a factory function that creates new scopes. You probably don't need to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer assumes you control most of the code here. The [codepile link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/X0mVbpvR) that was provided in the comment shows that the function in question is an override, and the parent class might be out of OP's control. If this method expects you to use the `Cursor` data synchronously, it might be better to stick with `runBlocking` (unless it's called on the main thread).

---

#### Original answer

The new code has 3 main problems:

1. `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` forces to switch to another thread pool (because the current dispatcher of the coroutine is `Main`), so it slows things down a bit. Moreover, Room uses its own dispatcher under the hood to implement its suspend functions, so it will also switch context there. This makes `withContext(IO)` not only redundant, but also harmful as it forces at least 2 context switches.
2. `launch` is not equivalent to `runBlocking`, because the execution becomes asynchronous. `runBlocking` returns only when everything inside its body has finished, including launched coroutines etc. However, now that you use `launch`, the call to `launch` will almost return immediately and you have no guarantee that the body will be finished when you move on. Whether this is OK or not really depends on the caller of your function, and more specifically what the caller does after the call (does it rely on the operations being completed?). This can drastically affect the behaviour your app, not only its performance (and the performance drop could be a side-effect of the behaviour change).
3. `CoroutineScope()` is a factory function that creates a new coroutine scope. Creating custom scopes is OK, but it should be done with care. The point of a coroutine scope is to control the lifecycle of the coroutines started in it. It is usually advised to create a coroutine scope in components with a lifecycle, and cancel the scope when the component is closed/destroyed/disposed of. When you create a scope as done in the OP's code, you don't keep a handle to this scope and cannot `cancel()` it when appropriate, effectively leaking coroutines. This is what [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency) is supposed to prevent.

The solution to problem #1 is just to remove the `withContext` wrappers. You should not need them.

For problem #2, I cannot really answer the question as it depends on the context, and there is not enough information here.

For problem #3, you have multiple options. Some examples of what you can do:

- make your function `suspend` instead of creating a scope and `launch`-ing a coroutine. This means you're moving the responsibility of creating a coroutine up the call stack, allowing the caller to choose the scope. If you do this, make sure you wrap your UI update in `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` so that it's run in the main thread regardless of the current context of the caller
- make the caller pass a coroutine scope to your function by defining your function as an extension on `CoroutineScope` (or taking it as argument). Again make sure you update your UI in the Main thread like in the previous point (because you can't know here in which dispatcher you're going to run at that point). That can be done by passing a dispatcher to `launch` or by using `withContext` around the UI update like in the previous point.
- create a custom scope as a property of the class that is running this code, but in that case you need to make sure your class has some sort of lifecycle and that the scope is cancelled when your class's life ends.