# Why ExecutorService is much faster than Coroutines in this example? [Solved]

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, microbenchmark, jmh

**Update:**

I made 2 silly mistakes!

1. I submitted only 1 task in the executor service example
2. I forgot to await for the tasks to finish.

**Fixing the test, lead to all 3 examples having around `190-200 ms/op` latency.**

---

I created a benchmark comparison using [kotlinx-benchmark](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-benchmark) (uses [jmh](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh)) to compare coroutines and a threadpool when making a blocking call.

My rational behind such benchmark is

1. Coroutines will block the underlying thread when making a blocking call.
2. A Network call is generally blocking ()
3. In an average service, I need to make a million of network calls.
4. In such scenario will I get any benefit, if I use coroutines?

---

The benchmark I create simulates the blocking call using `Thread.sleep(10) // 10 ms block` and I need to create `1000` of them. I created 3 examples with following results

### Dispatchers.io

Used `Dispatchers.io`, which is the recommended way to handle IO operations.

```kotlin
    @Benchmark
    fun withCoroutines() {
        runBlocking {
            val coroutines = (0 until 1000).map {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
                    sleep(10)
                }
            }

            coroutines.joinAll()
        }
    }
```

**Avg time: 188.418 ms/op**

### Fixed Threadpool

`Dispatcher.IO` created `64` threads (the exact number is nondeterministic statically). So I kept `60` threads for a comparable scenario

```kotlin
    @Benchmark
    fun withExecutorService() {
        val executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(60)
        executors.submit { sleep(10) }
        executors.shutdown()
    }
```

**Avg time: 0.054 ms/op**

### Threadpool Dispatcher

Since the results were shocking I decided to use the same threadpool above as the dispatcher as

```kotlin
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(60).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

**Avg time: 206,260 ms/op**

---

### Questions

1. Why are coroutines performing exceptionally bad here?
2. With `limitedParallelism(10)` options coroutines performed much better at `30ms/op`. Default number of threads used by IO are `64`. Does that mean that coroutine scheduler is causing too many context switches, leading to poor performance. Still the performance is not close to that of threadpools
3. Am I correct to assume that the network calls are always blocking? Both executor service and coroutines schedules execution over underlying threads while not blocking the main thread, so they are the direct competitors.

Notes:
I am running `jmh` with

```kotlin
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 50)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
```

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/mangatmodi/kotlin-kafka-playground/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/mangatmodi/kotlin/CoroutinesVsThread.kt#L102)

Comment: Soon I will create a system benchmark where I will batches to Kafka as the network call.

Comment: There is something wrong. In `withCoroutines` you create 1000 coroutines but in `withExecutorService` you sumbit only one task, also `shutdown` does not wait for tasks to complete. `This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.`

Comment: Please could you update your question to include the imports? What is `sleep(10)`? If it's `Thread.sleep()` then that might be interfering. Additionally, calling `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) {}` [might be forcing a change in thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67920935/4161471).

Comment: @IR42 That was really stupid of me and good catch on the awaitTermination. The results are comparable, as I would actually expect.

Comment: I have voted to close the question